# Use pipe viewer when streaming directory through tar

Tags: linux, compression, tar, pipelining, progress-bar

I am currently streaming a directory over SSH after compressing it through tar:

```
tar cz /path/to/foo | pv | ssh HOSTNAME 'tar xmz && some-cool-command'
```

The issue is that `pv` doesn't know the total size of the stream so it cannot show me a proper progressbar. I could set it to the size of the `/path/to/foo` but that won't be correct as the stream is compressed.

Is there a way to work around this and get `pv` to show a proper progressbar?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. You don't know how much the `tar` (`gzip` actually) will compress your file(s), until you do that.

You might compress the files on your drive in advance and then show progress bar of the transfer only:

```
 tar cz /path/to/foo > /tmp/ar && pv /tmp/ar | ssh HOSTNAME 'tar xmz && some-cool-command'
```

but I don't think it is what you you want to achieve. Or you might get satisfied with the *approximate* size based on the original file, as you proposed.

Comment: Regarding overall progress, "no" is too pessimistic. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I could set it to the size of the `/path/to/foo` but that won't be correct as the stream is compressed.

Then let `pv` see the not-yet-compressed stream.

`tar cz …` pipes to `gzip` "internally". You can build your pipeline with `tar` and explicit `gzip` instead:

```
tar c … | gzip -c | ssh …
```

Note there is no `z` in the options of `tar` now. Put `pv` between `tar` and `gzip` and it will see the not-yet-compressed stream:

```
tar c … | pv | gzip -c | ssh …
```

The total size of the stream seen by this `pv` can be estimated. I would estimate it using:

- `du --summarize --bytes /path/to/foo | cut -f 1`
- or `du --summarize --block-size=1 /path/to/foo | cut -f 1` in case of `tar --sparse`.

Personally I like to have `pv -cN …` before and after `gzip`, so I can roughly calculate compression ratio on the fly, usually just out of curiosity or for fun.